# how to configure page_offset and end in pdfkit

Tags: ruby, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I have pdfkit successfully installed in my app. The output pdf file for any given html that is passed has some extra pages that I don't need. Page 2 is the only relevant page that I will need from the html files in the current project. The following configure block isn't working as it should for the page_offset. Also is there a way to set the ending page; in my case I would offset and end on page 2.

```
kit = PDFKit.new(File.new("#{@LOCAL_HTML_DIR}/#{html}.html"))
          PDFKit.configure { |config| config.default_options = { :page_size => 'Letter', :margin_top => '0.5in', :margin_right => '0.5in', :margin_bottom => '0.7in', :margin_left => '0.5in', :zoom => 2, :page_offset => 2 }}
          file = kit.to_file("#{@LOCAL_HTML_DIR}/#{html}.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe page_offset should be a number, not a string:

:page_offset => 2

instead of

:page_offset => '2'

Comment: I tried that originally and it still didn't work; any thoughts on the end option, does pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf respectively support an end page?

Comment: page_offset works for me with wkhtmltopdf patched with QT. Are you using a binary, or a package (homebrew/rpm/etc.?) In the wkhtmltopdf documentation, it's noted that page_offset is 'only available using patched QT (http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html).'

Comment: wkhtmltopdf --version
Name: wkhtmltopdf 0.9.9